# Pages ’09: How to write Nested SUM?

Tags: macos, mac, pages

I'm setting up a basic time registration form for declarable hours spent on a project.
The layout is easy: *date — time from — time until — description*.
I want a cell-value to contain the sum of hours worked on a project (time until - time from).

I would say the correct formula would be `=SOM(SOM(D9-C9):SOM(D40-C40))` (I'm using the Dutch version). But this isn't working. My registration starts from row 9.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.. `:` must be `;`. My mistake..